# Laravel Show Two tables in the same page ( taking the id after the click of the search button )

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, routes

So my problem is :
i have a page and when i click search i bring the client last name
after that i want the car that has the same ClientId as the client been searched.

and to show it in the same page.

i tried many things and always get errors.

here's my code:

***the new task page :***

```
 <form action="{{ route('receptions.newtask') }}" method="GET">

                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-sm-3  "><label for="" class=" col-form-label" id="search">Last Name
                            search:</label></div>

                    <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ClientSearchbylastname" placeholder="Last Name">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill m-2">Search</button>

                    </div>
                </div>

                @foreach ($clients as $d)
                    @csrf
                    <div class="row mb-3">

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $d->id }}" name="clientidsearch" hidden>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-primary">Client Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $d->ClientName }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-primary">Client Lastname:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $d->ClientLastname }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-primary">Client Cin:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $d->ClientCin }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-primary">Client Phone:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $d->ClientPhone }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill m-2">Show car</button>

                    </div>

                    @foreach ($cars as $c)
                    @csrf
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-primary">Car Model:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $c->model }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @endforeach

                    @endforeach
            </form>
        </div>
```

***the Controller***

```
public function Newtask(Request $request){



    // $clients = Client::all();
    // return view('receptions.newtask',compact('clients'));
    $recherche = $request->get('ClientSearchbylastname');


    $clients = $recherche ? Client::where([['ClientLastName', 'LIKE', '%'.$recherche.'%']])->get() : [];
    
    $rechercheid = $request->get('clientidsearch');

    $cars = $rechercheid ? Car::where([['clientId', 'LIKE', '%'.$rechercheid.'%']])->get() : [];

   // $cars = DB::table('cars')->get();


    // $clientId = DB::table('Client')->where('ClientLastName', $clients->ClientId)->value('ClientId');
   //$cars =$clients ? Car::where([['ClientId', 'LIKE', '%'.$id.'%']])->get() :[];

    return view('receptions.newtask',compact('clients','cars'));

}
```

***Client model***

```
 public function Car()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Car::class, 'clientId');
}
```

***Car model***

```
 Public function Client(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
}
```

Comment: 'ClientLastName', $clients->ClientId ? I think you have an error. You may want to use relations from laravel. $client->cars; directly will give you cars of the client

Comment: It didn't work i tried the   `$client->car->model`   and it's not working

Comment: just use $client->car not client->car->model

Comment: It shows an empty `[]`  on the model field.

Comment: You also have erros on your query. You trying to get your clieng from clientLastName and client id. I think you should read laravel documentation to get better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can make searches according to your userIds. You had some errors while trying to get cars. Here I've fixed it:

```
$recherche = $request->get('ClientSearchbylastname');
$rechercheid = $request->get('clientidsearch');
$clientIds = $recherche ? Client::where('ClientLastName', 'LIKE', '%'.$recherche.'%')->get() : [];
$clientIds = array_merge($clientIds, $rechercheid ?? []);
$cars = Car::whereIn('clientId', $clientIds)->get();
    
return view('receptions.newtask',compact('cars'));
```